# Perl Syntax help

Tags: perl

I am new in perl and Can anyone explain me below command to understand what is purpose of using  $t[1]-- and timelocal(1,1,1,reverse @t).

Below command used to convert timestamp into epoch format. but please explain me use of this command $t[1]-- and timelocal(1,1,1,reverse @t).

```
perl -MTime::Local=timelocal -e '@t = split(/[-\/]/, $ARGV[0]); $t[1]--; print timelocal(1,1,1,reverse @t);' $date
```

Comment: what is the output of the command. were you able to run it?

Answer (score 3):

An example is in order:

```
perl -MTime::Local=timelocal -e '
    @t = split(/[-\/]/, $ARGV[0]);
    $t[1]--;
    print timelocal(1,1,1,reverse @t);
' "2016-10-18"
```

Will print out an epoch date (seconds since Jan 1, 1970)

```
1476766861
```

Having a look at the documentation: [perldoc Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) we see that:

> It is worth drawing particular attention to the expected ranges for the values provided. The value for the day of the month is the actual day (ie 1..31),
>   while the month is the number of months since January (0..11). This is
>   consistent with the values returned from localtime() and gmtime().

The first statement splits the string `2016-10-18` by dashes and slashes into the array `@t = (2016, 10, 18)`.  Perl arrays are 0-based by default, so `$t[1]` means the second item, i.e. the month, here set to `10`.  Since `localtime` takes months in the range `(0-11)` we need to subtract `1`, setting `$t[1]` to `9`.  The last statement just converts the date parts back into epoch time, reversing `@t` to match the order of arguments to timelocal:

```
 #       timelocal( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year )
 $time = timelocal(     1,    1,    1,    18,    9,  2016 ); # time in seconds = 1476766861
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great explnation. it helps me a lot for understand.Once again thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

It subtracts 1 from first component. Of the @t array.
I this is the Month field.
Note: First [1], not Zeroth [0].

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=665996

Regards,

Vern.